# Select the first and last row by group in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

How can I select the first and last row for each unique `id` in the following dataframe?

```
tmp <- structure(list(id = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L), d = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), gr = c(2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), mm = c(3.4, 
4.9, 4.4, 5.5, 4, 3.8, 4, 4.9, 4.6, 2.7, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2), area = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", 
"d", "gr", "mm", "area"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
tmp
#>    id d gr  mm area
#> 1  15 1  2 3.4    1
#> 2  15 1  1 4.9    2
#> 3  15 1  1 4.4    1
#> 4  15 1  1 5.5    2
#> 5  21 1  1 4.0    2
#> 6  21 1  2 3.8    2
#> 7  22 1  1 4.0    2
#> 8  22 1  1 4.9    2
#> 9  22 1  2 4.6    2
#> 10 23 1  1 2.7    2
#> 11 23 1  1 4.0    2
#> 12 23 1  2 3.0    2
#> 13 24 1  1 3.0    2
#> 14 24 1  1 2.0    3
#> 15 24 1  1 4.0    2
#> 16 24 1  2 2.0    3
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

A [plyr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=plyr) solution (`tmp` is your data frame):

```
library("plyr")
ddply(tmp, .(id), function(x) x[c(1, nrow(x)), ])
#    id d gr  mm area
# 1  15 1  2 3.4    1
# 2  15 1  1 5.5    2
# 3  21 1  1 4.0    2
# 4  21 1  2 3.8    2
# 5  22 1  1 4.0    2
# 6  22 1  2 4.6    2
# 7  23 1  1 2.7    2
# 8  23 1  2 3.0    2
# 9  24 1  1 3.0    2
# 10 24 1  2 2.0    3
```

Or with [dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr) (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528981/)):

```
library("dplyr")
tmp %>%
group_by(id) %>%
slice(c(1, n())) %>%
ungroup()
# # A tibble: 10 × 5
#       id     d    gr    mm  area
#    <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int>
# 1     15     1     2   3.4     1
# 2     15     1     1   5.5     2
# 3     21     1     1   4.0     2
# 4     21     1     2   3.8     2
# 5     22     1     1   4.0     2
# 6     22     1     2   4.6     2
# 7     23     1     1   2.7     2
# 8     23     1     2   3.0     2
# 9     24     1     1   3.0     2
# 10    24     1     2   2.0     3
```

Answer (score 124):

A fast and short [`data.table`](http://r-datatable.com) solution :

```
tmp[, .SD[c(1,.N)], by=id]
```

where `.SD` represents each (S)ubset of (D)ata, `.N` is the number of rows in each group and `tmp` is a `data.table`; e.g. as provided by `fread()` by default or by converting a `data.frame` using `setDT()`.

Note that if a group only contains one row, that row will appear twice in the output because that row is both the first and last row of that group. To avoid the repetition in that case, thanks to @Thell:

```
tmp[, .SD[unique(c(1,.N))], by=id]
```

Alternatively, the following makes the logic explicit for the `.N==1` special case :

```
tmp[, if (.N==1) .SD else .SD[c(1,.N)], by=id]
```

You don't need `.SD[1]` in the first part of the `if` because in that case `.N` is `1` so `.SD` must be just one row anyway.

You can wrap `j` in `{}` and have a whole page of code inside `{}` if you like. Just as long as the last expression inside `{}` returns a `list`- like object to be stacked (such as a plain `list`, `data.table` or `data.frame`).

```
tmp[, { ...; if (.N==1) .SD else .SD[c(1,.N)] } , by=id]
```

Comment: `.SD[unique(c(1,.N))]` for when a group has a single member.

Comment: borrowing from data camp
`setkey(tmp,id)` and `tmp[, .SD[c(1,.N)], .EACHI]`

Comment: @Kerry I have to admit I didn't know `setkey(tmp,id); tmp[, .SD[c(1,.N)], .EACHI]` would work without any i present. Where exactly is it on DataCamp?  Thanks.

Comment: @MattDowle it can be found on Chapter 3 > exercise: *Selecting groups or parts of groups*: *Use `by = .EACHI` and `.SD` to select the first and last row of the "b" and "c" groups.* and in the exercise `DT[c("b","c"), .SD[c(1,.N)], by= .EACHI]
# The first row of the "b" and "c" groups` great course btw

Comment: @C8H10N4O2  But there `i` is present.  Is it on DataCamp course *without i present*?

Comment: Another method would be `tmp[ tmp[, .I[c(1, .N)], by = id]$V1 ]` , and you can also use `.I[unique(c(1, .N))]` for duplicates

Comment: @SymbolixAU Using `.I` for this is getting a bit complicated and for large groups `.I` would be constructed wastefully only to use the first and last from it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution in base `R`.  If there are multiple groups with the same `id` this code returns the first and last row for each of those individual groups.

**EDIT: January 12, 2017**

This solution might be a little more intuitive than my other answer farther below:

```
lmy.df = read.table(text = '
     id    d    gr     mm  area
     15    1     2   3.40     1
     15    1     1   4.90     2
     15    1     1   4.40     1
     15    1     1   5.50     2
     21    1     1   4.00     2
     21    1     2   3.80     2
     22    1     1   4.00     2
     23    1     1   2.70     2
     23    1     1   4.00     2
     23    1     2   3.00     2
     24    1     1   3.00     2
     24    1     1   2.00     3
     24    1     1   4.00     2
     24    1     2   2.00     3
', header = TRUE)

head <- aggregate(lmy.df, by=list(lmy.df$id), FUN = function(x) { first = head(x,1) } )
tail <- aggregate(lmy.df, by=list(lmy.df$id), FUN = function(x) {  last = tail(x,1) } )
head$order = 'first'
tail$order = 'last'

my.output <- rbind(head, tail)
my.output
#   Group.1 id d gr  mm area order
#1       15 15 1  2 3.4    1 first
#2       21 21 1  1 4.0    2 first
#3       22 22 1  1 4.0    2 first
#4       23 23 1  1 2.7    2 first
#5       24 24 1  1 3.0    2 first
#6       15 15 1  1 5.5    2  last
#7       21 21 1  2 3.8    2  last
#8       22 22 1  1 4.0    2  last
#9       23 23 1  2 3.0    2  last
#10      24 24 1  2 2.0    3  last
```

**EDIT: June 18, 2016**

Since posting my original answer I have learned it is better to use `lapply` than `apply`.  This is because `apply` does not work if every group has the same number of rows.  See here: [Error when numbering rows by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285815/error-when-numbering-rows-by-group)

```
lmy.df = read.table(text = '
     id    d    gr     mm  area
     15    1     2   3.40     1
     15    1     1   4.90     2
     15    1     1   4.40     1
     15    1     1   5.50     2
     21    1     1   4.00     2
     21    1     2   3.80     2
     22    1     1   4.00     2
     23    1     1   2.70     2
     23    1     1   4.00     2
     23    1     2   3.00     2
     24    1     1   3.00     2
     24    1     1   2.00     3
     24    1     1   4.00     2
     24    1     2   2.00     3
', header = TRUE)


lmy.seq <- rle(lmy.df$id)$lengths
lmy.df$first <- unlist(lapply(lmy.seq, function(x) seq(1,x)))
lmy.df$last  <- unlist(lapply(lmy.seq, function(x) seq(x,1,-1)))
lmy.df

lmy.df2 <- lmy.df[lmy.df$first==1 | lmy.df$last == 1,]
lmy.df2

#   id d gr  mm area first last
#1  15 1  2 3.4    1     1    4
#4  15 1  1 5.5    2     4    1
#5  21 1  1 4.0    2     1    2
#6  21 1  2 3.8    2     2    1
#7  22 1  1 4.0    2     1    1
#8  23 1  1 2.7    2     1    3
#10 23 1  2 3.0    2     3    1
#11 24 1  1 3.0    2     1    4
#14 24 1  2 2.0    3     4    1
```

Here is an example in which each group has two rows:

```
lmy.df = read.table(text = '
     id    d    gr     mm  area
     15    1     2   3.40     1
     15    1     1   4.90     2
     21    1     1   4.00     2
     21    1     2   3.80     2
     22    1     1   4.00     2
     22    1     1   6.00     2
     23    1     1   2.70     2
     23    1     2   3.00     2
     24    1     1   3.00     2
     24    1     2   2.00     3
', header = TRUE)

lmy.seq <- rle(lmy.df$id)$lengths

lmy.df$first <- unlist(lapply(lmy.seq, function(x) seq(1,x)))
lmy.df$last  <- unlist(lapply(lmy.seq, function(x) seq(x,1,-1)))
lmy.df

lmy.df2 <- lmy.df[lmy.df$first==1 | lmy.df$last == 1,]
lmy.df2

#   id d gr  mm area first last
#1  15 1  2 3.4    1     1    2
#2  15 1  1 4.9    2     2    1
#3  21 1  1 4.0    2     1    2
#4  21 1  2 3.8    2     2    1
#5  22 1  1 4.0    2     1    2
#6  22 1  1 6.0    2     2    1
#7  23 1  1 2.7    2     1    2
#8  23 1  2 3.0    2     2    1
#9  24 1  1 3.0    2     1    2
#10 24 1  2 2.0    3     2    1
```

**Original answer:**

```
my.seq <- data.frame(rle(my.df$id)$lengths)

my.df$first <- unlist(apply(my.seq, 1, function(x) seq(1,x)))
my.df$last  <- unlist(apply(my.seq, 1, function(x) seq(x,1,-1)))

my.df2 <- my.df[my.df$first==1 | my.df$last == 1,]
my.df2

   id d gr  mm area first last
1  15 1  2 3.4    1     1    4
4  15 1  1 5.5    2     4    1
5  21 1  1 4.0    2     1    2
6  21 1  2 3.8    2     2    1
7  22 1  1 4.0    2     1    3
9  22 1  2 4.6    2     3    1
10 23 1  1 2.7    2     1    3
12 23 1  2 3.0    2     3    1
13 24 1  1 3.0    2     1    4
16 24 1  2 2.0    3     4    1
```

Answer (score 2):

### use `slice_head()` and `slice_tail()`

```
library(tidyverse)

tmp <- structure(list(id = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L), d = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), gr = c(2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), mm = c(3.4, 
4.9, 4.4, 5.5, 4, 3.8, 4, 4.9, 4.6, 2.7, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 2), area = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

tmp %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_head()
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   id [5]
     id     d    gr    mm  area
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int>
1    15     1     2   3.4     1
2    21     1     1   4       2
3    22     1     1   4       2
4    23     1     1   2.7     2
5    24     1     1   3       2
```

```
tmp %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice_tail()
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   id [5]
     id     d    gr    mm  area
  <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int>
1    15     1     1   5.5     2
2    21     1     2   3.8     2
3    22     1     2   4.6     2
4    23     1     2   3       2
5    24     1     2   2       3
```

### Note that:

By default, `slice_head()` and `slice_tail()` return 1 row, but you can also specify the arguments `n` and `prop` with slice a number of rows or a proportion of rows respectively. See `?slice` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach utilizing `dplyr` could be:

```
tmp %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter(1:n() %in% range(1:n()))

      id     d    gr    mm  area
   <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <int>
 1    15     1     2   3.4     1
 2    15     1     1   5.5     2
 3    21     1     1   4       2
 4    21     1     2   3.8     2
 5    22     1     1   4       2
 6    22     1     2   4.6     2
 7    23     1     1   2.7     2
 8    23     1     2   3       2
 9    24     1     1   3       2
10    24     1     2   2       3
```

Or the same idea with using `row_number()`:

```
tmp %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter(row_number() %in% range(row_number()))
```

Or performing the operation with `slice()`:

```
tmp %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 slice(c(which.min(1:n()), which.max(1:n())))
```

Comment: I think you'd only need `which.min()` and `which.max()` if you were looking for the top and bottom row of an unsorted data frame by a specific column. In this case, where it's just first and last row you can use `slice(1, n())`

Comment: @Gregor Thomas that is certainly true, I've just provided some variations on the existing themes :) For some users it may be more meaningful or straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `ave` in base R. For each `id` we select the first and last row.

```
tmp[as.logical(with(tmp,ave(d, id, FUN = function(x) 
                    seq_along(x) %in% c(1L, length(x))))), ]

#   id d gr  mm area
#1  15 1  2 3.4    1
#4  15 1  1 5.5    2
#5  21 1  1 4.0    2
#6  21 1  2 3.8    2
#7  22 1  1 4.0    2
#9  22 1  2 4.6    2
#10 23 1  1 2.7    2
#12 23 1  2 3.0    2
#13 24 1  1 3.0    2
#16 24 1  2 2.0    3
```

A shorter version would be using `range`, `range` returns minimum and maximum value from the vector

```
tmp[as.logical(with(tmp, ave(seq_along(d), id,FUN = function(x) x %in% range(x)))),]
```

---

We can also use `split` + `sapply` approach with `range`

```
tmp[c(sapply(split(seq_len(nrow(tmp)), tmp$id), range)), ]
```

---

Using `dplyr`, although I would prefer the `slice` approach shown by @rcs but here is one way using `filter` which is similar to `ave` solution where we create a logical vector by comparing `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)
tmp %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(row_number() %in% c(1L, n()))
```

In all the above solution, we can also use `match` instead of `%in%` as `%in%` is just a wrapper around `match`.