# How to subtract first entry from last entry in grouped data

Tags: r, dataframe

I would appreciate some help with the following task: From the data frame below (`C`), for each id I would like to subtract the first entry under column `d_2` from the final entry and then store the results in another dataframe containing the same ids. I can then merge this with my initial dataframe. Pls note that the subtraction has to be in this order (last entry minus first entry for each `id`).

Here are the codes:

```
id <- c("A1", "A1", "B10","B10", "B500", "B500", "C100", "C100", "C100", "D40", "D40", "G100", "G100")

d_1 <- c( rep(1.15, 2), rep(1.44, 2), rep(1.34, 2), rep(1.50, 3), rep(1.90, 2), rep(1.59, 2))

set.seed(2)

d_2 <- round(runif(13, -1, 1), 2)

C <- data.frame(id, d_1, d_2)

id   d_1   d_2
A1   1.15 -0.63
A1   1.15  0.40
B10  1.44  0.15
B10  1.44 -0.66
B500 1.34  0.89
B500 1.34  0.89
C100 1.50 -0.74
C100 1.50  0.67
C100 1.50 -0.06
D40  1.90  0.10
D40  1.90  0.11
G100 1.59 -0.52
G100 1.59  0.52
```

Desired result:

```
id2 <- c("A1", "B10", "B500", "C100", "D40", "G100")

difference <- c(1.03, -0.81, 0, 0.68, 0.01, 1.04)

diff_df <- data.frame(id2, difference)

id2    difference
A1        1.03
B10      -0.81
B500      0.00
C100      0.68
D40       0.01
G100      1.04
```

I attempted this by using `ddply` to obtain the first and last entries but I'm really struggling with indexing the "function argument" in the second code (below) to get the desired outcome.

```
C_1 <- ddply(C, .(id), function(x) x[c(1, nrow(x)), ])

ddply(C_1, .(patient), function )
```

To be honest, I'm not very familiar with the ddply package-I got the code above from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203818/how-to-select-the-first-and-last-row-within-a-grouping-variable-in-a-data-frame) on stack exchange .

My original data is a groupedData and I believe another way of approaching this is using `gapply` but again I'm struggling with the third argument here (usually a function)

```
grouped_C <- groupedData(d_1 ~ d_2 | id, data = C, FUN = mean, labels = list( x = "", y = ""), units = list(""))

x1 <- gapply(grouped_C, "d_2", first_entry)

x2 <- gapply(grouped_C, "d_2", last_entry)
```

where first_entry and last_entry are functions to help me get the first and and last entries.
I can then get the difference with: `x2 - x1`. However, I'm not sure what to input as first_entry and last_entry in the above codes (perhaps to do with head or tail ?).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be done easily with `dplyr`. The `last` and `first` functions are very helpful for this task.

```
library(dplyr)               #install the package dplyr and load it into library 

diff_df <- C %>%             #create a new data.frame (diff_df) and store the output of the following operation in it. The %.% operator is used to chain several operations together but you dont have to reference the data.frame you are using each time. so here we are using your data.frame C for the following steps
  group_by(id) %>%            #group the whole data.frame C by id
  summarize(difference = last(d_2)-first(d_2))     #for each group of id, create a single line summary where the first entry of d_2 (for that group) is subtracted from the last entry of d_2 for that group

#    id difference             #this is the result stored in diff_df
#1   A1       1.03
#2  B10      -0.81
#3 B500       0.00
#4 C100       0.68
#5  D40       0.01
#6 G100       1.04
```

---

Edit note: updated post with `%>%` instead of `%.%` which is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, much appreciated. Do you mind explaining the syntax and the various parts of the code? etc. Its my first time using this package.

Comment: @John Sure. I added comments to explain the operations in my answer. For more details on `dplyr`, have a look at this introduction to the package (http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html)

Comment: @ beginneR-cool name by the way! Thank you so much, the comments were very helpful but I'll also go through the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: @docendo Warning messages:
1: '%.%' is deprecated.
Use '%>%' instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any singletons and they need to be left alone, then this will solve your problem.  It's the same as docendo discimus's answer, but with an `if-else` component to deal with the singleton cases:

```
library(dplyr)               
diff_df <- C %>%             
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarize(difference = if(n() > 1) last(d_2) - first(d_2) else d_2)
```