# Grouping ordered dataframe based on two variables

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

I have a dataframe as below:

```
     Id         DateTIme Status
 1: 101 10/01/2014 09:32     On
 2: 101 10/01/2014 10:50     On
 3: 101 10/01/2014 21:32    Off
 4: 101 11/01/2014 15:32    Off
 5: 101 11/01/2014 21:21    Off
 6: 127 10/01/2014 10:13    Off
 7: 127 11/01/2014 20:21    Off
 8: 127 11/01/2014 23:10    Off
 9: 127 12/01/2014 12:02    Off
10: 127 12/01/2014 21:00     On
11: 127 13/01/2014 03:24     On
12: 763 11/01/2014 12:01    Off
13: 763 11/01/2014 22:10    Off
14: 763 12/01/2014 09:32     On
15: 763 13/01/2014 09:21     On
16: 763 13/01/2014 20:23     On
17: 763 14/01/2014 15:12     On
18: 763 14/01/2014 23:51    Off
19: 763 15/01/2014 09:23    Off
```

The dataframe is order by Id and DateTime.

I need to find the initial and end time for each Status change, for each Id. So, in this case I would expect to output something like this:

```
    Id Status      InitialTime          EndTime
1: 101     On 10/01/2014 09:32 10/01/2014 10:50
2: 101    Off 10/01/2014 21:32 11/01/2014 21:21
3: 127    Off 10/01/2014 10:13 12/01/2014 12:02
4: 127     On 12/01/2014 21:00 13/01/2014 03:24
5: 763    Off 11/01/2014 12:01 11/01/2014 22:10
6: 763     On 12/01/2014 09:32 14/01/2014 15:12
7: 763    Off 14/01/2014 23:51 15/01/2014 09:23
```

Comment: If reshaping isn't important. Have a look [How to select the first and last row within a grouping variable in a data frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203818/how-to-select-the-first-and-last-row-within-a-grouping-variable-in-a-data-frame) You can obviously do it later easily.

Comment: From the link, you can use with `dplyr` , `df %>%group_by(Id, Status) %>%
  slice(c(1, n()))`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the OP's data is already a `data.table`.  In case, it is not, convert to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Id', 'Status' and the run-length-id of 'Status', we get the first 'DateTIme' and last 'DateTIme' to summarise the dataset to have 'InitialTime' and 'EndTime' columns (respectively)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(InitialTime = DateTIme[1L], EndTime=DateTIme[.N]) , 
   .(Id, Status, Status1 = rleid(Status))][, Status1 := NULL][]
#    Id Status      InitialTime          EndTime
#1: 101     On 10/01/2014 09:32 10/01/2014 10:50
#2: 101    Off 10/01/2014 21:32 11/01/2014 21:21
#3: 127    Off 10/01/2014 10:13 12/01/2014 12:02
#4: 127     On 12/01/2014 21:00 13/01/2014 03:24
#5: 763    Off 11/01/2014 12:01 11/01/2014 22:10
#6: 763     On 12/01/2014 09:32 14/01/2014 15:12
#7: 763    Off 14/01/2014 23:51 15/01/2014 09:23
```