# How to duplicate last row by group (ID)?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I have a data.frame of surfaces touched over time. I would like to simply append a duplicate of the last row for each AcvitivityID:

```
head(movsdf.rbind)
  ActivityID CareType HCWType Orientation    Surface       Date     Time       Dev.Date.Time SurfaceCategories
1         01       IV    RN01  leftFacing AlcOutside 2019-08-03 11:08:01 2019-08-03 11:08:01       HygieneArea
2         01       IV    RN01  leftFacing         In 2019-08-03 11:08:12 2019-08-03 11:08:12                In
3         01       IV    RN01  leftFacing       Door 2019-08-03 11:08:12 2019-08-03 11:08:12        FarPatient
4         02       IV    RN01  leftFacing       Door 2019-08-03 11:08:18 2019-08-03 11:08:18        FarPatient
5         02       IV    RN01  leftFacing      Other 2019-08-03 11:08:22 2019-08-03 11:08:22        FarPatient
6         03       IV    RN01  leftFacing      Table 2019-08-03 11:10:26 2019-08-03 11:10:26       NearPatient
```

Example data:

```
movsdf.rbind<-data.frame(ActivityID=rep(1:4, each=10),Surface=rep(c("In","Table","Out"),each=10))
```

So I can get this to work from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203818/how-to-select-the-first-and-last-row-within-a-grouping-variable-in-a-data-frame) :

```
repeatss <- aggregate(movsdf.rbind, by=list(movsdf.rbind$ActivityID), FUN = function(x) { last = tail(x,1) })

movsdf.rbind <-rbind(movsdf.rbind, repeatss)
```

This does the trick but it looks clunky and then the data is not in order (not that it really matters but I feel something more elegant might exist in `dplyr` or `data.table`). Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please share a reproducible example of your data?

Comment: Do you mean `data.table` with `DT`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should write this more clearly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another alternative using `slice`:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  group_by(ActivityID) %>% 
  slice(c(1:n(),n()))
```

which gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 9
> # Groups:   ActivityID [3]
>   ActivityID CareType HCWType Orientation Surface    Date      Time     Dev.Date.Time     SurfaceCategori~
>        <int> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>       <chr>      <chr>     <chr>    <chr>             <chr>           
> 1          1 IV       RN01    leftFacing  AlcOutside 2019-08-~ 11:08:01 2019-08-03 11:08~ HygieneArea     
> 2          1 IV       RN01    leftFacing  In         2019-08-~ 11:08:12 2019-08-03 11:08~ In              
> 3          1 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Door       2019-08-~ 11:08:12 2019-08-03 11:08~ FarPatient      
> 4          1 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Door       2019-08-~ 11:08:12 2019-08-03 11:08~ FarPatient      
> 5          2 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Door       2019-08-~ 11:08:18 2019-08-03 11:08~ FarPatient      
> 6          2 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Other      2019-08-~ 11:08:22 2019-08-03 11:08~ FarPatient      
> 7          2 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Other      2019-08-~ 11:08:22 2019-08-03 11:08~ FarPatient      
> 8          3 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Table      2019-08-~ 11:10:26 2019-08-03 11:10~ NearPatient     
> 9          3 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Table      2019-08-~ 11:10:26 2019-08-03 11:10~ NearPatient
> ```

---

Two base R alternatives:

```
# one
lastrows <- cumsum(aggregate(CareType ~ ActivityID, DF, length)[[2]])
DF[sort(c(seq(nrow(DF)), lastrows)),]

# two
idx <- unlist(tapply(1:nrow(DF), DF$ActivityID, FUN = function(x) c(x, tail(x, 1))))
DF[idx,]
```

which both give the same result.

---

Two [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) alternatives:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)          # convert 'DF' to a data.table

# one
DF[DF[, .I[c(1:.N,.N)], by = ActivityID]$V1]

# two
DF[, .SD[c(1:.N,.N)], by = ActivityID]
```

---

Used data:

```
DF <- structure(list(ActivityID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L),
                     CareType = c("IV", "IV", "IV", "IV", "IV", "IV"),
                     HCWType = c("RN01", "RN01", "RN01", "RN01", "RN01", "RN01"),
                     Orientation = c("leftFacing", "leftFacing", "leftFacing", "leftFacing", "leftFacing", "leftFacing"),
                     Surface = c("AlcOutside", "In", "Door", "Door", "Other", "Table"),
                     Date = c("2019-08-03", "2019-08-03", "2019-08-03", "2019-08-03", "2019-08-03", "2019-08-03"),
                     Time = c("11:08:01", "11:08:12", "11:08:12", "11:08:18", "11:08:22", "11:10:26"),
                     Dev.Date.Time = c("2019-08-03 11:08:01", "2019-08-03 11:08:12", "2019-08-03 11:08:12", "2019-08-03 11:08:18", "2019-08-03 11:08:22", "2019-08-03 11:10:26"),
                     SurfaceCategories = c("HygieneArea", "In", "FarPatient", "FarPatient", "FarPatient", "NearPatient")),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you for all the examples!

Comment: Another base option: `DF[ rep(1:nrow(DF), 1 + !duplicated(DF$ActivityID, fromLast=TRUE)), ]` also similar to Ronak's

Answer (score 3):

One `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility could be (using sample data from @Jaap):

```
DF %>%
 group_by(ActivityID) %>%
 uncount((row_number() == max(row_number())) + 1)

  ActivityID CareType HCWType Orientation Surface   Date     Time   Dev.Date.Time   SurfaceCategori…
       <int> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>       <chr>     <chr>    <chr>  <chr>           <chr>           
1          1 IV       RN01    leftFacing  AlcOutsi… 2019-08… 11:08… 2019-08-03 11:… HygieneArea     
2          1 IV       RN01    leftFacing  In        2019-08… 11:08… 2019-08-03 11:… In              
3          1 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Door      2019-08… 11:08… 2019-08-03 11:… FarPatient      
4          1 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Door      2019-08… 11:08… 2019-08-03 11:… FarPatient      
5          2 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Door      2019-08… 11:08… 2019-08-03 11:… FarPatient      
6          2 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Other     2019-08… 11:08… 2019-08-03 11:… FarPatient      
7          2 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Other     2019-08… 11:08… 2019-08-03 11:… FarPatient      
8          3 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Table     2019-08… 11:10… 2019-08-03 11:… NearPatient     
9          3 IV       RN01    leftFacing  Table     2019-08… 11:10… 2019-08-03 11:… NearPatient
```

Or:

```
DF %>%
 group_by(ActivityID) %>%
 uncount((row_number() == n()) + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I would like to accept Jaap's for the extra code snippets.

Answer (score 3):

If we want to repeat only last row for each group it is enough to know last row number for each group. We can `duplicated` with `fromLast` argument as `TRUE` to get those row numbers and then add them with current rows. Using @Jaap's data

```
DF[sort(c(seq_len(nrow(DF)), which(!duplicated(DF$ActivityID, fromLast = TRUE)))),]


#    ActivityID CareType HCWType Orientation    Surface       Date     Time       Dev.Date.Time SurfaceCategories
#1            1       IV    RN01  leftFacing AlcOutside 2019-08-03 11:08:01 2019-08-03 11:08:01       HygieneArea
#2            1       IV    RN01  leftFacing         In 2019-08-03 11:08:12 2019-08-03 11:08:12                In
#3            1       IV    RN01  leftFacing       Door 2019-08-03 11:08:12 2019-08-03 11:08:12        FarPatient
#3.1          1       IV    RN01  leftFacing       Door 2019-08-03 11:08:12 2019-08-03 11:08:12        FarPatient
#4            2       IV    RN01  leftFacing       Door 2019-08-03 11:08:18 2019-08-03 11:08:18        FarPatient
#5            2       IV    RN01  leftFacing      Other 2019-08-03 11:08:22 2019-08-03 11:08:22        FarPatient
#5.1          2       IV    RN01  leftFacing      Other 2019-08-03 11:08:22 2019-08-03 11:08:22        FarPatient
#6            3       IV    RN01  leftFacing      Table 2019-08-03 11:10:26 2019-08-03 11:10:26       NearPatient
#6.1          3       IV    RN01  leftFacing      Table 2019-08-03 11:10:26 2019-08-03 11:10:26       NearPatient
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.

```
result <- lapply(split(movsdf.rbind, movsdf.rbind$ActivityID), function(DF){
  rbind(DF, DF[nrow(DF), ])
})
result <- do.call(rbind, result)

result
#     ActivityID value
#1.1           1     1
#1.2           1     2
#1.3           1     3
#1.31          1     3
#2.4           2     4
#2.5           2     5
#2.6           2     6
#2.61          2     6
#3.7           3     7
#3.8           3     8
#3.9           3     9
#3.91          3     9
```

If the new row numbers are ugly, they can be made consecutive with

```
row.names(result) <- NULL
```

**Data creation code.**

```
movsdf.rbind <- data.frame(ActivityID = rep(1:3, each = 3),
                           value = 1:9)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I would like to accept Jaap's for the extra code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

We can `split` then `map` to `bind_rows`ing each data frame with its last row

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
movsdf.rbind %>% 
      split(.$ActivityID) %>% 
      #Use map if you need the output as a list
      #instead of filter you can try slice(.x, n()) 
      map_df(~bind_rows(.x, filter(.x, row_number()==n())))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I would like to accept Jaap's for the extra code snippets.