# Deleting duplicated rows based on condition (position)

Tags: r, duplicates, data-manipulation

I have a dataset that looks something like this

```
df <- data.frame("id" = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha","Alpha","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta"), 
                 "Year" = c(1970,1970,1970,1971,1980,1980,1981,1982), 
                 "Val" = c(2,3,-2,5,2,5,3,5))
```

I have mulple observations for each id and time identifier - e.g. I have 3 different alpha 1970 values. I would like to retain only one observation per id/year most notably the last one that appears in for each id/year.
the final dataset should look something like this:

```
final <- data.frame("id" = c("Alpha","Alpha","Beta","Beta","Beta"), 
                    "Year" = c(1970,1971,1980,1981,1982), 
                    "Val" = c(-2,5,5,3,5))
```

Does anyone know how I can approach the problem?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: [Select first and last row from grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528981/select-first-and-last-row-from-grouped-data), [How to select the first and last row within a grouping variable in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203818/how-to-select-the-first-and-last-row-within-a-grouping-variable-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame("id" = c("Alpha", "Alpha", "Alpha","Alpha","Beta","Beta","Beta","Beta"), 
                 "Year" = c(1970,1970,1970,1971,1980,1980,1981,1982), 
                 "Val" = c(2,3,-2,5,2,5,3,5))

final <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(id, Year) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  ungroup()

final
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   id     Year   Val
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Alpha  1970    -2
#> 2 Alpha  1971     5
#> 3 Beta   1980     5
#> 4 Beta   1981     3
#> 5 Beta   1982     5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Translates to "within each id-Year group, take only the row where the row number is equal to the size of the group, i.e. it's the last row under the current ordering."

You could also use either `filter()`, e.g. `filter(row_number() == n())`, or `distinct()` (and then you wouldn't even have to group), e.g. `distinct(id, Year, .keep_all = TRUE)` - but `distinct` functions take the first distinct row, so you'd need to reverse the row ordering here first.

Comment: @Alessandro Happy to help. Please remember to accept the answer! :)

Comment: Sure, but the system blocks me if I accept the answer before 10 minutes. you have to be a little patient

Comment: @Alessandro Didn't know that!

Comment: Would you have some idea to do the opposite instead? i.e only selecting the first row? that would be extremely helpful as well!

Comment: Yep, that's just the `distinct()` solution I suggested, as-is. `distinct(id, Year, .keep_all = TRUE)`. Or slice by group with `n()` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are open to a `data.table` solution, this can be done quite concisely:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .SD[.N], by = c("id", "Year")]
#>       id Year Val
#> 1: Alpha 1970  -2
#> 2: Alpha 1971   5
#> 3:  Beta 1980   5
#> 4:  Beta 1981   3
#> 5:  Beta 1982   5
```

`by = c("id", "Year")` groups the data.table by `id` and `Year`, and `.SD[.N]` then returns the last row within each such group.

Answer (score 1):

An option with `base R`

```
aggregate(Val ~ ., df, tail, 1)
#     id Year Val
#1 Alpha 1970  -2
#2 Alpha 1971   5
#3  Beta 1980   5
#4  Beta 1981   3
#5  Beta 1982   5
```

If we need to select the first row

```
aggregate(Val ~ ., df, head, 1)
```

Comment: Would you have some idea to do the opposite instead? i.e only selecting the first row? that would be extremely helpful as well!

Comment: Thanks! that is great