# Convert list of dates to sequences

Tags: r, data.table, sequence, diff

I am trying to find sequences in a list of dates and convert them to a start and an end date.

An example of my data looks as follows:

```
    id  date
1   1   2020-01-01
2   1   2020-01-02
3   1   2020-01-03
4   1   2020-01-06
5   1   2020-01-07
6   2   2020-01-02
7   2   2020-01-03
8   2   2020-01-04
9   2   2020-01-05
10  3   2020-01-04
11  3   2020-01-07
```

What I would like to create is the following table:

```
    id  start date end date
1   1   2020-01-01 2020-01-03
2   1   2020-01-06 2020-01-07
3   2   2020-01-02 2020-01-05
4   3   2020-01-04 2020-01-04
5   3   2020-01-07 2020-01-07
```

I have been fiddling around with the diff function but I can't quite get it to work the way I want.

Comment: See [How to split a vector into groups of consecutive sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222061/how-to-split-a-vector-into-groups-of-consecutive-sequences) for the `cumsum(diff(...` idiom to create a grouping variable. Then [Select the first and last row by group in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203818/select-the-first-and-last-row-by-group-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
DT[, grp := cumsum(date - shift(date, 1L, fill = date[1]) > 1), by = id]
DT[, .(start_date = date[1], end_date = date[.N]), by = .(id, grp)][, !"grp"]

#    id start_date   end_date
# 1:  1 2020-01-01 2020-01-03
# 2:  1 2020-01-06 2020-01-07
# 3:  2 2020-01-02 2020-01-05
# 4:  3 2020-01-04 2020-01-04
# 5:  3 2020-01-07 2020-01-07
```

Reproducible data

```r
DT <- data.table(
  id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
  date = structure(
    c(18262, 18263, 18264, 18267, 18268, 18263, 18264, 18265, 18266, 18265, 18268), 
    class = "Date"
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R approach using `by` and `rle`.

```
res <- do.call(rbind, by(DF, DF$id, function(x) {
  cbind(id=x[1,1], setNames(
    do.call(rbind, Map(function(i, j) data.frame(i, i + j), 
                       x[c(0, diff(x[,2])) != 1, 2],
                       rle(cumsum(c(0, diff(x[,2])) != 1))$lengths - 1
    )), c("start", "end")))
}))
res
#     id      start        end
# 1.1  1 2020-01-01 2020-01-03
# 1.2  1 2020-01-06 2020-01-07
# 2    2 2020-01-02 2020-01-05
# 3.1  3 2020-01-04 2020-01-04
# 3.2  3 2020-01-07 2020-01-07
```

---

*Data:*

```
DF <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L), date = structure(c(18262, 18263, 18264, 18267, 18268, 18263, 
18264, 18265, 18266, 18265, 18268), class = "Date")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
 group_by(id, grp = cumsum(c(0, !diff(date) %in% 0:1))) %>%
 summarise(start_date = min(date),
           end_date = max(date))

     id   grp start_date end_date  
  <int> <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1     1     0 2020-01-01 2020-01-03
2     1     1 2020-01-06 2020-01-07
3     2     0 2020-01-02 2020-01-05
4     3     0 2020-01-04 2020-01-04
5     3     1 2020-01-07 2020-01-07
```

Comment: I assumed this has to be grouped by `id`, don't you think so?

Comment: @sindri_baldur you are totally right, missed it somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

One-liner (but not really different to other answers)

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), 
  date = lubridate::ymd('2020-01-01')+c(0:2,5,6,1:4,3,6))

# calculate
dt[, .(start = date[c(T, x <- diff(date) != 1)], end = date[c(x, T)]), id]

#>    id      start        end
#> 1:  1 2020-01-01 2020-01-03
#> 2:  1 2020-01-06 2020-01-07
#> 3:  2 2020-01-02 2020-01-05
#> 4:  3 2020-01-04 2020-01-04
#> 5:  3 2020-01-07 2020-01-07
```